# Query in Array with dates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to do a query(In MongoDB) in array("availability") that will return a only hotel that have the element("available") equals 1 and between the dates inside the availability.

But the query return all hotels when the correct return is "Mercato Hotel"

Query that i have used without success:

```
{city: "Boston", availability: { $elemMatch: {availability: 1, date: {$gte: ISODate("2015-05-02T00:00:00.000+0000")}, date: {$lte: ISODate("2015-05-04T00:00:00.000+0000")}}}}
```

Json in MongoDb:

```
 { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("55b302ee8debdf1a908cdc85"), 
        "city" : "Boston", 
        "hotel" : "Mercatto Hotel", 
        "availability" : [
            {
                "date" : ISODate("2015-05-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
                "available" : NumberInt(0)
            }, 
            {
                "date" : ISODate("2015-05-02T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
                "available" : NumberInt(0)
            }, 
            {
                "date" : ISODate("2015-05-03T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
                "available" : NumberInt(0)
            }, 
            {
                "date" : ISODate("2015-05-04T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
                "available" : NumberInt(1)
            }
        ]
    }
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("55b302ee8debdf1a908cdc89"), 
        "city" : "Boston", 
        "hotel" : "Hostel Villa", 
        "availability" : [
            {
                "date" : ISODate("2015-05-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
                "available" : NumberInt(1)
            }, 
            {
                "date" : ISODate("2015-05-02T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
                "available" : NumberInt(0)
            }, 
            {
                "date" : ISODate("2015-05-03T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
                "available" : NumberInt(0)
            }, 
            {
                "date: ISODate("2015-05-04T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
                "available" : NumberInt(0)
            }
        ]
    }
```

Someone can help me?

Thanks...

Answer (score 5):

You have got a typo in your query, `availability` instead of `available`, should be this:

```
{
    city: "Boston", 
    availability: {
            $elemMatch: {
                    available: 1, 
                    date: {
                        $gte: ISODate("2015-05-02T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
                        $lte: ISODate("2015-05-04T00:00:00.000+0000")
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** *with [Blakes Seven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5031275/blakes-seven)*

If you want to get only the element of `availability` array that matches your query, add projection:

```
{
    "city": 1,
    "hotel": 1
    "availability.$.date": 1
}
```

Comment: On the right track but basically the same as the OP's query. I think their gripe here is that the array in the document returned still has all the elements. So is there something you are not telling them here?

Comment: The OP wants a query *"...that will return a only hotel that have the element("available") equals 1..."*. In that case the original query is just fine, but has an error in the field name. However if the requirement is that only the elements of the `availability` array are returned that have `available` as `0`, then [Vishwas' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31623268/3264192) will perfectly work, if he adds a `$group` stage to the pipeline.

Comment: *Or* just show them how to use the [positional `$` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) to return the "one" match within the document array.

Comment: Updated, but if that's the case, the question needs to be redefined, agree? Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The query:

```
{
    city: "Boston", 
    availability: {
            $elemMatch: {
                    available: 1, 
                    date: {
                        $gte: ISODate("2015-05-02T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
                        $lte: ISODate("2015-05-04T00:00:00.000+0000")
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Returned the same result. In other words, returned all hotels when the correct return is "Mercato Hotel".

Answer (score 2):

You can use [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) to get expected output as following:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$availability"
}, {
    $match: {
    "city": "Boston",
    "availability.available": 1,
    "availability.date": {
        $gte: ISODate("2015-05-02T00:00:00.000+0000"),
        $lte: ISODate("2015-05-04T00:00:00.000+0000")
    }
    }
})
```

**Edit**

If there are multiple `available=1` then use following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$availability"
}, {
    $match: {
    "city": "Boston",
    "availability.available": 1,
    "availability.date": {
        $gte: ISODate("2015-05-02T00:00:00.000+0000"),
        $lte: ISODate("2015-05-04T00:00:00.000+0000")
    }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
    _id: "$hotel",
    "city": {
        $first: "$city"
    },
    "availability": {
        $push: "$availability"
    }
    }
})
```

Comment: Aggregation is redundant here, and except the `$unwind` stage, the rest is the same as the OP's original query.

Comment: @n9code Aggregation is used to get only those documents where `availability.available` is `1`.  `find` will return all array containing `availability.available = 0` as well as `1`.  In short it will return whole array if any match find.

Comment: I agree, but the the problem OP has is in his query itself, and he does not state that he/she needs only the element of the array that has `available` as `1`. Besides if there are multiple elements with `available` equals `1`, the result will be multiple document. So you will need to add a `$group` stage as well.